# solidity ecrecovery and ethereumjs ecsign return different address

Tags: web3js, contract-development, ethereumjs

I have a code as follow using `web3 0.2` and `ethereumjs-util` to interact with smart contract. What exactly am i doing it wrong? is it incompatible between ecsign of ehtereumjs with smart contract ecrecovery? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you send `sig` to contract? Will it work for you to send all parts separately?

```
function ecrecover(bytes32 msgHash, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) constant returns(address) {
    bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
    bytes32 prefixedHash = keccak256(prefix, msgHash);
    return ecrecover(prefixedHash, v, r, s);
}
```

You can find more working examples: https://github.com/davidmichaelakers/ecrecover

**UPDATE:**

In case if you need to send signature to contract, I think you need to add `prefix` in your code. `web3` does it for you, that can be a reason of different results

```
bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
bytes32 prefixedHash = keccak256(prefix, msgHash);
```

**UPDATE 2: Working solution**

Dependencies:

```
Truffle v4.1.8 (core: 4.1.8)
Solidity v0.4.23 (solc-js)

"chai": "^4.1.1",
"chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
"chai-bignumber": "^2.0.1",
"ethereumjs-util": "^5.2.0",
"mocha": "^3.5.0",
"truffle-contract": "^2.0.5"
```

Smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract Test {
    function ecrecover(bytes32 msgHash, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) constant returns (address) {
        return ecrecover(msgHash, v, r, s);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
const EthUtil = require('ethereumjs-util')

const Test = artifacts.require("./Test.sol");
const BigNumber = web3.BigNumber
const should = require('chai')
    .use(require('chai-as-promised'))
    .use(require('chai-bignumber')(BigNumber))
    .should()

contract.only('Test', function (accounts) {
    beforeEach(async function () {
        this.contract = await Test.new();
    })

    it.only("ecrecover: should pass", async function () {
        const message = EthUtil.sha3('Message to sign here.')
        const signature = await EthUtil.ecsign(message, new Buffer('907570bfd5e48faa71b59fd6d48c9d12dfd639ff0c5f715e9211feb7abfa5edf', 'hex') )

        const recoveredAddress = await this.contract.ecrecover(
            '0x' + message.toString('hex'),
            signature.v,
            '0x' + signature.r.toString('hex'),
            '0x' + signature.s.toString('hex'));
        recoveredAddress.should.be.equal('0x5e54317f3599ea5d026baaca7d9857abeca9c01d', 'The recovered address should match the signing address')
    })
}
```

Comment: no it didn't work. still getting wrong address when i sign in ethereumjs and using above function in solidity contract

Comment: Unfortunately i didn't get it work with your code. You can refer to the image (of hash, v,r,s inputted) that i run in solidity. The address found from ecrecover is `0x26Bc...` which is not same as `0x5e5...`.  I am using the same ethereumjs-util version https://image.ibb.co/ms1fJe/Capture.png

Comment: which network and version of compiler in remix do you use?

Comment: javascript vm, remix 0.4.23. does it matter which network?

Comment: it is matter, because it helps to understand where your code executes, otherwise it is not clear.

Comment: I found an issue, and updated contract above

Comment: thanks it working. any idea why does the previous smart contract code with kecak256 above work for you in truffle?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on this solution since few weeks and was able to make it working for onchain (using solidity) verification..

I had the same concern where i was able to verify off chain using web3 ethereumjs-util lib but when I was trying with solidity then it was returrning me 0x000000000

The approach I had taken was as following, try out if that works for you

const data = await tokenContractInstance.methods.transfer(escrow, amountForERC20).encodeABI(); // a new version of web3 1.x

```
    // https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1609
    let txObj = {
        "chainId": chainId,
        "from": sender,
        "nonce": web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
        "to": tokenContractAddress,
        "value": '0x0',
        "gasPrice": web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice),
        "gasLimit": web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit), // also knows as gas
        "data": data
    };

    // version 2
    txObj = web3.utils.toHex(txObj);
    txObj = web3.utils.sha3(txObj);
    let messagetoSign = txObj;

    await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(sender, "poc@2018");
    let signature = await web3.eth.sign(messagetoSign, sender);
    let signatureData = ethUtil.fromRpcSig(signature);
    let v = ethUtil.bufferToHex(signatureData.v);
    let r = ethUtil.bufferToHex(signatureData.r);
    let s = ethUtil.bufferToHex(signatureData.s);
    verifyContractInstance.methods.ecrecover(messagetoSign, v, r, s).call();     
    console.log("Signed Address --> ", receivedAddress);
```

solidity code --->

```
function ecrecover(bytes32 msgHash, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public pure returns(address) {
    bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
    bytes32 prefixedHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(prefix, msgHash));
    return ecrecover(prefixedHash, v, r, s);
}
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Regards
Dev

Comment: @stackdisplay .. I have just read two last comments in which you have mentioned that you were able to get it solved using your previous approach and updated the Smart Contract ..

Could you please share the approach and details ..

Regards

Comment: u can refer to the updated post message by aquila above on the updated smart contract. not sure with web3.eth.sign as i am working with ethereumutil ecsign

Comment: Yup I got it, I tried it before but did you try to check what happens if you try to verify the TxObj instead of a message string..

Comment: you can hash txObj as shown in here. There is very specific implementation of that https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/865#issuecomment-362609538 here