# Geth ecrecover function returning '0x'

Tags: go-ethereum, ecrecover

can someone help me with this ecrecover issue? The code below is a truffle test. The recoverSigner function just calls ecrecover, but the return is always '0x'. Recovering with ethereumjs-util works fine.

Geth v1.8.17 (clique private network)
Truffle v4.1.14
Solidity v0.4.24

```js
//Front-end
const msg = new Buffer('hello')
const sig = web3.eth.sign(web3.eth.accounts[0], '0x' + msg.toString('hex'))

//Back-end
const res = ethUtil.fromRpcSig(sig)
const prefix = new Buffer("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n")
const prefixedMsg = ethUtil.keccak256(Buffer.concat([prefix, New Buffer(String(msg.length)), msg]))
const pubKey  = ethUtil.ecrecover(prefixedMsg, res.v, res.r, res.s)
const addrBuf = ethUtil.pubToAddress(pubKey)
const addrEthJS = ethUtil.bufferToHex(addrBuf)
assert.equal(accounts[0], addrEthJS) // Ok!

//Ethereum Network
let addrSolidity = await instance.recoverSigner(ethUtil.bufferToHex(prefixedMsg), res.v, ethUtil.bufferToHex(res.r), ethUtil.bufferToHex(res.s))
assert.equal(accounts[0], addrSolidity) // Fail! recoverSigner returns '0X'
```

Answer (score 1):

`0x` means you pass not valid parameters.

Take a look the answer [solidity ecrecovery and ethereumjs ecsign return different address](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/59880/solidity-ecrecovery-and-ethereumjs-ecsign-return-different-address/59884#59884)

Comment: Thank You for you answer. There was a failure in 6 of the 8 tests at the repo indicated on the link. The 2 success cases were in the ecrecover3 function. All others returned '0x'.

Comment: @Robert not sure about what tests you are talking, I see only one test there

Comment: I was talking about https://github.com/davidmichaelakers/ecrecover test cases.

Comment: @Robert it causes because you have different versions of compiler and packages. I think the answer in similar question should work for you. Take a look section UPDATE 2: Working solution