# Error: [ethjs-abi] invalid hex or buffer, must be a prefixed alphanumeric even length hex string

Tags: web3js, erc-20, metamask

While recovering address from hash and sign, getting above error.

```
myHash = '0xd0109ef5f602b69354acd389a2c752f9b80ef6bbce92a922ae8853d43a027b68';

mySign = '0xebedaa7185fe2b0c4a6a6e3f1a833abd14eeb2f05f46931ec5c602e9f67a43af2071e9bcda9a1598dcc9e936ceea71d95d648f9c390c1ef6d58fd01012e2ab4e1c';

var getRecoveredAddress = function (myHash, mySign) 
{
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        token.recover(myHash, mySign
            , (error, result) => {
                if (error) reject(error);
                console.log(result)
                resolve(result);
            })
    });
};
```

Please let me know what what's wrong with this code!! Thank you in advance!

Comment: How the signature was generated? What does `token.recover` works?

Comment: myHash was returning an array object. myHash[0] solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: my ERC865 contract recovering the correct address after generating the sign using Metamask customized function web3.eth.sign() using [this](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsign). But when I try normal web3.eth.accounts.sign() using [this](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#sign), I'm getting wrong address. I want to sign the hash using private key only!(I know, which is not acceptable!!)

Comment: I have created contract referring [this](https://github.com/adilharis2001/ERC865Demo).

Comment: @Ismael Please suggest the correct way to recover the address

Comment: See if this answer can help you https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/59884, it has a full example working.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks a lot! Will work on it and then let you know..

Comment: @Ismael I tried the solution you suggested but no success as I'm not adding prefix before hash. Now generating the sign using Ganache-cli, and getting different sign. That means Meatamask and Ganche-cli generating different signs for the same hash and that's why I'm getting different addresses!! Is there any way to get the exact sign as generated by Metamask? **Using the same method - web3.eth.sign(from, hash)**

Comment: There's an issue in ganache about signing https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/issues/243

Answer (score 2):

Try switching to different network in metamask, then switching back. Could be some cached state if you're using ganache and have restarted it.

I got that error message after restarting ganache, and metamask being connected to same server+port already before restart.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Thanks.